# Variable declared outside of a loop is unidentified inside C++

Tags: c++, identifier

I have a C++ program writen in Microsoft Visual Studio (I've just started learning). Here's my code:

```
else
    // time is in seconds
    int time = 0;
    double speed = 0.0;
    while (height >= 0)
    {
        cout << "At " << int time << " secs the ball is at height: " << height << " metres.\n";
        time++;
        height -= distanceTravelled(speed);
        speed += gravity;
    }

    // If height dropped from positive to negative in one second, the final fraction of a 
    // second before it hits the ground isn't displayed - so the if statement
    if (height <= 0)
        cout << "At " << time << " secs the ball is at height: " << height << " metres.\n";
```

When I'm trying to build it I am getting an error

> "time" is an undeclared identifier.

But I've declared it outside of the while loop. So why can't it be found?

Comment: Is `<< int  time <<` actual part of the code?  What is it expected to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems in the code you've posted. One is a spurious `int` on the output line. It should be just this:

```
cout << "At " << time << " secs the ball is at height: " << height << " metres.\n";
```

The second problem is that your `else` is missing braces. This means that only the declaration of `time` is inside the `else` branch, and everything else is on the same level as the condition (indentation does not count in C++). So it should look like this:

```
else
{
    // time is in seconds
    int time = 0;
    double speed = 0.0;
    while (height >= 0)
    {
        cout << "At " << time << " secs the ball is at height: " << height << " metres.\n";
        time++;
        height -= distanceTravelled(speed);
        speed += gravity;
    }

    // If height dropped from positive to negative in one second, the final fraction of a 
    // second before it hits the ground isn't displayed - so the if statement
    if (height <= 0)
        cout << "At " << time << " secs the ball is at height: " << height << " metres.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are declaring a new variable within your cout statement:

cout << "At " << **int** time << " secs the ball is at height: " << height << " metres.\n";

Just remove the **int**

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem right here:

```
else      //<==== missing paranthesis
   // time is in seconds
   int time = 0;
   double speed = 0.0;
```

You lack a open paranthesis after else. What actually happens is that the first statement after else is the false-branch of the if-else statement. What comes after that is NOT. So all code after the line with *double speed = 0.0;* is outside of the if-statement which is not visible in your code excerpt.

Which in effect makes the *int time* be in a complete other scope than the code further down accessing this.. That's why the code accessing the *int time* variable, can not find it.

To fix: add a { after else and add a } further down to encompass your logic.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem is in this line.

```
cout << "At " << int time << " secs the ball is at height: " << height << " metres.\n";
```

`int time` should be replaced by just `time` here.

Datatype is specified with a variable only when defining it, as in `int time`, or when casting it, as in `(int)time`. You are simply printing an `int` variable.

I cannot reproduced the exact same error you are facing with a g++ compiler, but changing the above may solve it.